# Read return value as string by Mathlink.h

Tags: mathlink-or-wstp, big-numbers

I'm using "mathlink.h" to call *Mathematica* from a C program. I send a computation to *Mathematica* and its return result is a very big number (100 digits). Hence, I want to read that number as a string.

How can I do it using *MathLink*?

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could simply wrap your computation in

```c
MLPutFunction(link, "ToString", 1);
```

and convert your result to a string. After that you can use `MLGetString`.

Comment: One problem is if the output is an expression, say $x^2 + x + 1$, then the ToString method will return in un-readable format. What should I do if I want to read arbitrary output as a string? Like for the expression above, I expect to get output as exactly $x^2 + x + 1$.

Comment: and I see there is no other option for ToString method.

Comment: @Loi.Luu You question was how you can send very big *numbers* as string through MathLink. Why do you now want to send expressions? Addtionally, `ToString[x^2 + x + 1, InputForm]` gives a string of valid *Mathematica* syntax.

Comment: Sorry to make you confused, I thought I can apply the same technique to expression. You are correct in both answers, thank you for your help :)